# Modify Global Navigation CSOM

Tags: navigation, office-365, client-object-model

Can I modify the Global Navigation by using CSOM against a publishing site in SharePoint Online. What I would like to achieve is to hide some of the navigation elements in the global top navigation.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.navigationnodecollection_members%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.navigationnode_members%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for information on `NavigationNodeCollection` and `NavigationNode` respectively.  This will need to be changed depending on whether this is done in an app, console app or [PowerShell](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sharepointnutsandbolts.com%2F2013%2F12%2FUsing-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html&ei=enNnU9J_5eewBLqygJgK&usg=AFQjCNGcaB1Xjb63vKnXAgDwmea9UEAOGA&sig2=fQ30T3nZVLJlhGRFzzhQCg).

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
{
    context.Credentials = credentials;

    NavigationNodeCollection qlNodes = context.Web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
    context.Load(qlNodes);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    qlNodes.ToList().ForEach(node => node.DeleteObject());
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

See [SharePointOnlineCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.sharepointonlinecredentials%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to create credentials (if this is in a console app or PowerShell).

Comment: I have the publishing feature enabled so I don't think that going against web.navigation does help, at least it returned 0 nodes in my case.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  You need to use the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing` namespace then.  I found this [link](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-change-navigation.html) on changing the navigation with Publishing (it's JSOM, but it can be done with CSOM with minor edits).  However, it seems there are only methods to change the term store, so you'd have to be using Managed Metadata driven navigation.

Comment: Yep that seems like the way I'm heading. To bad that we can't handle standard publishing navigation with CSOM but working with navigation has always been quite confusing in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SPNavigation.TopNavigationBar property](https://mayak82.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx) to manage the nodes in Global Navigation.

Then you could delete navigation nodes as demonstrated below:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     ctx.Credentials = credentials;
     var topNavBar = ctx.Web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar; //get Global Navigation
     ctx.Load(topNavBar);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     topNavBar.ToList().ForEach(node => node.DeleteObject());
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
 }
```